# OOM killer beeing invoked by snapd systemd timer, CPU usage locks at 100% (snapd, mount, certbot)

Tags: debian, mount, certbot, oom, snap

Im having trouble debugging why my nodeJS webapp gets killed by the OOM killer in Debian 11. Im working on a small VPS (VMware ESX 7.0.3 build-21313628) by IONOS with single core 1GHz cpu, 512MB RAM, 1,9GB swap and 10GB SSD.

The webapp runs with pm2 and nginx as a reverse proxy, im using certbot systemd timer for automatic SSL renewals.

The issue which occurs is the following: The VPS gets unresponsive and i get a "critical ping" alert. The stats in the IONOS dashboard most of the time show cpu usage going to 100% and staying there, as well as a drop in RAM usage and no more responsiveness when pinging. It happens randomly, sometimes after a week or two of running, sometimes after 2 days. A software reboot of the server helps to resolve the issues.
In normal operation, the RAM usage is at ~15-30% and CPU usage is at ~10%.

I took a look at the logs from the OOM killer and it seems that the issue always happens when mounting for either snapd itself or certbot.

```
localhost systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for certbot, revision 3024...
mount invoked oom-killer
```

See the full logs attached below:

```
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:02 localhost snapd[749]: storehelpers.go:769: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "certbot", "core20"
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:11 localhost systemd[1]: Reloading.
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:12 localhost systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for snapd, revision 19122...
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.827965] mount invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x40cc0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP), order=3, oom_score_adj=0
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828070] CPU: 0 PID: 34164 Comm: mount Not tainted 5.10.0-19-amd64 #1 Debian 5.10.149-2
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828102] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 11/12/2020
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828144] Call Trace:
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828275]  dump_stack+0x6b/0x83
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828312]  dump_header+0x4a/0x1f4
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828335]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828379]  out_of_memory+0x1bd/0x4e0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828410]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0xbcc/0xc90
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828439]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2de/0x310
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828464]  kmalloc_order+0x28/0x100
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828486]  kmalloc_order_trace+0x19/0x90
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828520]  xz_dec_lzma2_create+0x21/0x80
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828543]  xz_dec_init+0x54/0xa0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828574]  squashfs_xz_init+0x3d/0x60 [squashfs]
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828597]  squashfs_decompressor_create+0x75/0x110 [squashfs]
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828623]  squashfs_decompressor_setup+0x82/0x180 [squashfs]
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828658]  squashfs_fill_super+0x338/0x8d0 [squashfs]
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828713]  ? init_once+0x10/0x10 [squashfs]
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828747]  get_tree_bdev+0x16d/0x260
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828771]  vfs_get_tree+0x22/0xc0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828793]  path_mount+0x458/0xa70
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828820]  __x64_sys_mount+0x107/0x140
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828848]  do_syscall_64+0x30/0x80
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828875]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xc6
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828910] RIP: 0033:0x7f7fdc52e62a
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.828930] Code: 48 8b 0d 69 18 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 83 c8 ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 89 ca b8 a5 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 36 18 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.829032] RSP: 002b:00007ffdb673a008 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000a5
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.829139] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007f7fdc662264 RCX: 00007f7fdc52e62a
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.829184] RDX: 0000563cc5ff0c80 RSI: 0000563cc5ff0c60 RDI: 0000563cc5ff7f90
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.829223] RBP: 0000563cc5ff0a30 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f7fdc600be0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.829259] R10: 0000000000000005 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.829287] R13: 0000563cc5ff7f90 R14: 0000563cc5ff0c80 R15: 0000563cc5ff0a30
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.829323] Mem-Info:
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.830356] active_anon:1169 inactive_anon:1417 isolated_anon:0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.830356]  active_file:734 inactive_file:980 isolated_file:0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.830356]  unevictable:0 dirty:12 writeback:6
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.830356]  slab_reclaimable:6041 slab_unreclaimable:47488
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.830356]  mapped:1105 shmem:21 pagetables:1039 bounce:0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.830356]  free:1799 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.834868] Node 0 active_anon:4676kB inactive_anon:5668kB active_file:2936kB inactive_file:3920kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:4420kB dirty:48kB writeback:24kB shmem:84kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:5904kB all_unreclaimable? no
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.837038] Node 0 DMA free:1680kB min:96kB low:120kB high:144kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:16kB inactive_anon:44kB active_file:8kB inactive_file:4kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB pagetables:212kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.839128] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 388 388 388 388
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.839795] Node 0 DMA32 free:5516kB min:2472kB low:3088kB high:3704kB reserved_highatomic:2048KB active_anon:4660kB inactive_anon:5628kB active_file:2932kB inactive_file:3912kB unevictable:0kB writepending:32kB present:507776kB managed:434640kB mlocked:0kB pagetables:3944kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.841869] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.842599] Node 0 DMA: 9*4kB (U) 76*8kB (U) 65*16kB (UE) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 1684kB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.844121] Node 0 DMA32: 339*4kB (UMEH) 196*8kB (UMEH) 131*16kB (UMEH) 6*32kB (H) 1*64kB (H) 2*128kB (H) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 5532kB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.845672] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.846466] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.847312] 3047 total pagecache pages
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.848215] 1313 pages in swap cache
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.849004] Swap cache stats: add 16848324, delete 16847011, find 6908638/14622802
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.849850] Free swap  = 1846492kB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.850673] Total swap = 1998844kB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.855457] Name                      Used          Total
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.856289] nf_conntrack             127KB        127KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.857122] ext4_system_zone           3KB          3KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.857977] scsi_sense_cache         296KB        296KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.858798] PINGv6                    30KB         30KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.859626] RAWv6                    339KB        339KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.860423] UDPv6                     31KB         31KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.861217] tw_sock_TCPv6             15KB         15KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.862019] request_sock_TCPv6         15KB         15KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.862763] TCPv6                     30KB         30KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.863490] mqueue_inode_cache         31KB         31KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.864215] UNIX                     200KB        200KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.864939] RAW                      512KB        512KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.865671] UDP                       31KB         31KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.866386] tw_sock_TCP               15KB         15KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.867130] request_sock_TCP          15KB         15KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.867852] TCP                      122KB        122KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.868540] hugetlbfs_inode_cache         31KB         31KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.869224] eventpoll_pwq             15KB         15KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.869907] request_queue             63KB         63KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.870618] biovec-max               272KB        368KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.871278] biovec-128                32KB         32KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.871961] biovec-64                 32KB         32KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.872574] dmaengine-unmap-256         30KB         30KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.873165] dmaengine-unmap-128         31KB         31KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.873786] dmaengine-unmap-16        165KB        165KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.874333] skbuff_fclone_cache         32KB         32KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.874903] skbuff_head_cache        400KB        400KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.875429] file_lock_cache            7KB          7KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.875932] fsnotify_mark_connector          8KB          8KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.876455] net_namespace             30KB         30KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.876962] task_delay_info           51KB         51KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.877422] taskstats                 15KB         15KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.877859] proc_dir_entry           149KB        149KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.878275] pde_opener                 3KB          3KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.878687] seq_file                   7KB          7KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.879065] shmem_inode_cache        759KB        759KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.879446] kernfs_node_cache       6076KB       6076KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.879814] mnt_cache                239KB        239KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.880184] filp                     322KB        448KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.880541] names_cache               64KB         64KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.880887] lsm_file_cache            51KB         51KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.881232] uts_namespace             15KB         15KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.881582] vm_area_struct           767KB        914KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.881925] mm_struct                 64KB         82KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.882267] files_cache              147KB        147KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.882621] signal_cache             441KB        441KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.882962] sighand_cache            682KB        744KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.883300] task_struct             2202KB       2315KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.883635] cred_jar                 102KB        102KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.883972] anon_vma_chain           205KB        268KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.884311] anon_vma                 226KB        304KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.884643] pid                       64KB         64KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.884975] Acpi-Operand             452KB        452KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.885308] Acpi-Parse                 7KB          7KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.885641] Acpi-State                 7KB          7KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.885968] numa_policy               47KB         47KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.886292] trace_event_file         158KB        158KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.886628] ftrace_event_field        398KB        398KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.886952] pool_workqueue            64KB         64KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.887277] task_group                74KB         74KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.887603] vmap_area                144KB        144KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.887931] kmalloc-8k               448KB        448KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.888256] kmalloc-4k            116840KB     116840KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.888579] kmalloc-2k              3808KB       3808KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.888900] kmalloc-1k              1733KB       1828KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.889218] kmalloc-512            14202KB      15024KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.889570] kmalloc-256             1056KB       1056KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.889888] kmalloc-192              252KB        252KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.890201] kmalloc-128              264KB        264KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.890515] kmalloc-96               200KB        200KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.890839] kmalloc-64               556KB        556KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.891149] kmalloc-32               480KB        480KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.891456] kmalloc-16               200KB        200KB
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.891767] kmalloc-8                 80KB         80KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.892063] kmem_cache_node           12KB         12KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.892357] kmem_cache                48KB         48KB
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.892681] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.892975] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.893310] [    337]     0   337    36649       67   274432      224          -250 systemd-journal
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.893639] [    352]     0   352     5461       93    69632      309         -1000 systemd-udevd
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.893969] [    419]   101   419    22110        0    73728      192             0 systemd-timesyn
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.894303] [    436]     0   436    12569        0    86016      368             0 VGAuthService
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.894661] [    437]     0   437    59708       33    90112      290             0 vmtoolsd
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.895006] [    640]     0   640    24972        5    73728      335             0 dhclient
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.895354] [    688]     0   688    24972        0    69632      375             0 dhclient
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.895696] [    744]     0   744     2319       23    53248       42             0 cron
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.896040] [    745]   104   745     1990       49    49152       95          -900 dbus-daemon
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.896392] [    748]     0   748    55199        0    81920      593             0 rsyslogd
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.896805] [    749]     0   749   184028      508   241664     4259          -900 snapd
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.897173] [    751]     0   751     3475       58    73728      213             0 systemd-logind
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.897541] [    753]     0   753   302239        0   274432     2909          -999 containerd
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.897934] [    757]     0   757     2094        0    49152       28             0 agetty
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.898339] [    761]     0   761     3339        8    65536      235         -1000 sshd
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.898731] [    785]     0   785   310713        0   364544     5526          -500 dockerd
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.899112] [   1024]  1000  1024     3859       23    69632      349             0 systemd
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.899496] [   1026]  1000  1026    25612        2   102400      763             0 (sd-pam)
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.899884] [   3877]  1000  3877   205117        1   942080     5054             0 PM2 v5.2.2: God
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.900278] [   4064]  1000  4064  2828374      423  1187840     7610             0 node /var/www/t
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.900679] [   5675]     0  5675    56818        0   176128     6802             0 nginx
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.901131] [  22752]    33 22752    56818        4   172032     6776             0 nginx
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.901546] [  34163]     0 34163     3167        5    65536       51          -900 systemctl
/var/log/syslog.1-May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.901963] [  34164]     0 34164     2392      139    61440       20             0 mount
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.902384] [  34166]     0 34166     5461      325    65536      250             0 systemd-udevd
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.902830] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=snap-snapd-19122.mount,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope,task=node /var/www/t,pid=4064,uid=1000
/var/log/syslog.1:May  2 16:10:13 localhost kernel: [168329.903824] Out of memory: Killed process 4064 (node /var/www/t) total-vm:11313496kB, anon-rss:1692kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:1160kB oom_score_adj:0
```

The systemd timer for certbot ssl renewal looks like this:

```
[Unit]
# Auto-generated, DO NOT EDIT
Description=Service for snap application certbot.renew
Requires=snap-certbot-3024.mount
Wants=network.target
After=snap-certbot-3024.mount network.target snapd.apparmor.service
X-Snappy=yes

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment
ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap run --timer="00:00~24:00/2" certbot.renew
SyslogIdentifier=certbot.renew
Restart=no
WorkingDirectory=/var/snap/certbot/3024
TimeoutStopSec=30
Type=oneshot
```

Im not sure how to continue debugging at this point. I could not find any meaningful information online. Is the VPS just too small in terms of CPU and RAM or is there anything I can do about it to prevent the problem?

Comment: Disable memory overcommit and prevent [the out-of-fuel killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/) from tossing passengers out of the airplane....  As a bonus you'll find the miscreant process that complains about not getting enough memory.

Comment: And according to my calculations, the 2828374 `total_vm` value for your `node` process means it's asked for 2828374 4kb pages of RAM, or 11,585,019,904 bytes.  That's 11 GB on a system with 512 MB of RAM and under 2 GB of swap.  That is not going to end well.

Comment: I will disable memory overcommit to see if that helps. I also saw that node has a high vm consumption, but in their github repo it says that this is practically not a problem, and that vm on x64 systems is theoretically unlimited: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39499 If the system still runs out of memory because of snapd, and I can not remove it as a service, is there any other possible solution instead of increasing actual physical RAM available?

Comment: 512 MB RAM is way too low for anything other than very basic services (eg: SSH jumphost). So yes - your VPS is simply too small.